# Autocommit in Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

How do I set initilize my Flask application to set Flask-SQLAlchemy to autocommit mode, to not use transactions unless I explicitly `session.begin()`?

The session "[begins a database transaction as soon as it starts communicating](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/session.html)". Does this affect Postgres **harder** than MySQL?

---

By [Instagram](http://instagram-engineering.tumblr.com/post/40781627982/handling-growth-with-postgres-5-tips-from-instagram),

> autocommit mode; in this mode, Psycopg2 won’t issue BEGIN/COMMIT for
>   any queries; instead, every query runs in its own single-statement
>   transaction. This is particularly useful for read-only queries where
>   transaction semantics aren’t needed. It’s as easy as doing:
>
> connection.autocommit = True
>
> This lowered chatter between our application servers and DBs
>   significantly, and lowered system CPU as well on the database boxes

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think you can set `autocommit` in Flask-SQLAlchemy doing this:

```
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
db = SQLAlchemy(session_options={'autocommit': True})
```

Edit: the 'flask.ext.' form is now depricated (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47116912/python-flask-ext-mysql-is-deprecated))

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
db = SQLAlchemy(session_options={'autocommit': True})
```

Comment: Yes, somebody made a pattern for a transaction-bound session and an autocommited session like https://gist.github.com/dittos/6396622

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using Flask-SQLAlchemy, it has `autocommit = False` by default. See this [code here](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-sqlalchemy/blob/master/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py#L147)

It does say that if you want to turn on autocommit to True by default, you will have to override the `SQLAlchemy.create_session` function.