# Set autocommit=True in Flask-SQLAlchemy after DB instantiation

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have my flask_models in a separate file that looks like:

```
db = SQLAlchemy()
class SomeObj(db.Model):
    ...

class SomeOtherObj(db.Model):
    ...
```

Then I import that `db` wherever needed. Currently, I'm importing it into my tests. For those, I'd like to set autocommit to true. Is there any way to do this to an already existent `db`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Autocommit in Flask-SQLAlchemy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25197871/autocommit-in-flask-sqlalchemy)

Comment: You just need to read the last three words of the title to see how the question is different.