# Python flask.ext.mysql is deprecated?

Tags: python, mysql, flask

When I run `from flask.ext.mysql import MySQL` I get the warning `Importing flask.ext.mysql is deprecated, use flask_mysql instead`.

So I installed flask_mysql using `pip install flask_mysql`,installed it successfully but then when I run `from flask_mysql import MySQL` I get the error `No module named flask_mysql`. In the first warning I also get  `Detected extension named flaskext.mysql, please rename it to flask_mysql. The old form is deprecated.
  .format(x=modname), ExtDeprecationWarning`. Could you please tell me how exactly should I rename it to flask_mysql? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`flask.ext.` is a deprecated pattern which was used prevalently in older extensions and tutorials. The warning is telling you to replace it with the direct import, which it guesses to be `flask_mysql`. However, Flask-MySQL is using an even more outdated pattern, `flaskext.`. There is nothing you can do about that besides convincing the maintainer to release a new version that fixes it. `from flaskext.mysql import MySQL` should work and avoid the warning, although preferably the package would be updated to use `flask_mysql` instead.

Answer (score 0):

`flask.ext.X` is the old form to import a Flask extension, it is deprecated since Flask v0.10. The new way is to use `flask_X`. That's why you got the first warning.

But apparently, Flask-MySQL does not update it's name form and use the `flaskext` as the package name (chedck it on [GitHub](https://github.com/cyberdelia/flask-mysql/)). That's why you got the second warning.

Comment: so, is there any solution to avoid these warnings?

Comment: [create an issue](https://github.com/cyberdelia/flask-mysql/issues) to request the maintainer to fix it.