# How to enable autocommit mode for PostgreSQL in Flask with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, flask-sqlalchemy

I’ve got a system that runs a PostgreSQL database, and uses Flask with SQLAlchemy to interact with it. A number of the queries are failing, and because SQLAlchemy automatically starts transactions behind the scenes, we’re getting a lot of PostgreSQL processes locked up in `idle in transaction (aborted)` status.

Now, I know that the proper thing to do is to fix those queries and improve the exception handling, but that’s easier said than done. It’s in the pipeline, but in the meantime I need a quick mitigation, and turning on autocommit looks like it will fix 99% of the current operational issues. Less critical, but I’d also like to avoid spurious transactions for queries that don’t alter database state - this system is an API and most of the calls are `SELECT`s. I’m quite happy managing my own transactions and telling the database when I need them. Most of the time for this application, they aren’t necessary and I don’t want the extra overhead.

I’ve read https://www.oddbird.net/2014/06/14/sqlalchemy-postgres-autocommit/ and [Autocommit in Flask-SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25197871/autocommit-in-flask-sqlalchemy). Unless I’m very much mistaken, the solution given in that Stack Overflow thread turns on what Carl Meyer described as “emulated autocommit”. This system is under very high load and if at all possible I’d like to avoid the extra overhead of requiring a `commit()` after every `SELECT` (the implicit requirement of which doesn’t seem like a sensible decision on the part of SQLAlchemy, but I digress).

Here's a minimal snippet of the database initialisation in the Flask app:

```py
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask import Flask

#db = SQLAlchemy( engine_options = { 'isolation_level': 'AUTOCOMMIT' } )
# line above fails with “TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'engine_options'”
db = SQLAlchemy( session_options = { 'autocommit': True } )
# this version works, but I think it’s emulated autocommit rather than true (default) PostgreSQL autocommit

def register_extensions(app):
    db.init_app(app)
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__.split('.')[0])
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql+psycopg2://localhost/etc'
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS'] = { 'isolation_level': 'AUTOCOMMIT' }
    # line above has no effect, gets ignored
    register_extensions(app)
    return app

app = create_app()
```

Not sure whether any of this is version specific, but for what it’s worth we’re running on a vanilla Ubuntu 20.04 stack: python3-flask-sqlalchemy 2.1, python3-sqlalchemy 1.3.12, python 3.8.2, postgresql 12.8. Flask is served by Apache 2.4.41 using `mod_wsgi`.

If I still had hair I would be tearing it out at this point. Is what I’m trying to do possible, and if so, how?

*EDIT:* According to the Flask SQLAlchemy documentation at https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/api/#flask_sqlalchemy.SQLAlchemy, `engine_options` is one of the expected arguments for the `SQLAlchemy` constructor, so I'm not sure why it's failing in the example above.

*EDIT 2:* I just spotted that `engine_options` wasn’t added until Flask SQLAlchemy 2.4, whereas we’re on version 2.1, so that explains why that’s failing. The question remains, is there another way of passing in the option? Because various other parts of the code need access to the `db` object, I don’t think I can call `create_engine()` directly.

Comment: What DB-API connector are you using, and what version?

Comment: Related docs https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html#setting-transaction-isolation-levels-including-dbapi-autocommit, https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html#library-level-e-g-emulated-autocommit, (if psycopg2 is the DB-API connector https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/postgresql.html#psycopg2-transaction-isolation-level)

Comment: We’re using `postgresql+psycopg2`. I’ve read the documentation that you linked, but (a) it's for a different version of SQLAlchemy (1.4 instead of 1.3), and (b) the code there isn’t directly applicable because it’s hidden behind Flask’s methods.

Comment: `app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS'] = { 'isolation_level': 'AUTOCOMMIT' }` works for me, SQLAlchemy still logs commit and rollbacks, but if you look in the Postgres logs you can see these statements aren't present. (this is documented [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_transaction.html?highlight=isolation#setting-isolation-for-a-sessionmaker-engine-wide)).

Comment: On the connections ending up in a bad state: Flask SQLAlchemy ought to automatically remove sessions when a request ends, at which point it should reset or close the connection.  It seems odd that the connections are being left in such a state (unless they are so broken that a rollback can't fix them).

Comment: Yes, very strange. I've double checked and `app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS'] = { 'isolation_level': 'AUTOCOMMIT' }` doesn't work for me. Running a query (via Flask) without an explicit commit produces `FATAL:  terminating connection due to idle-in-transaction timeout` in the PostgreSQL logs. However I can't see any sign of commit or rollback in the PostgreSQL logs regardless of what connection options I use in Flask, with or without explicit commits.

Comment: Very odd.  Are you able to create a [mre], and share it and the output of SQLAlchemy's logging when it is run?